# datepicker call back not working in IE

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using datepicker with php and jQuery to show events however this script will not work in IE and I cant figure out why.  I think it has something to do with the $.get jQuery but not sure why this will not work

```
<?
// DB CONNECTION
?>

<link type="text/css" href="/css/calendar-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<?
// DB QUERY DB
$sql = "SELECT MONTH(eStart) as mon, DAY(eStart) as day, YEAR(eStart) as year FROM events WHERE eStart LIKE '%$date%' ORDER BY eStart ASC";
$rows = $db->query($sql);
while ($record = $db->fetch_array($rows)) {

    $dates .= "new Date(".$record[year].", ".$record[mon]."-1, ".$record[day]."),";

}

$dates = rtrim($dates, ',');

?> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


    var dates = [<?= $dates; ?>];


        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: [1,1],
            beforeShowDay: highlightDays
        });


        $('#datepicker').click(function(evt){
            // put your selected date into the data object
            var data = $('#datepicker').val();


            $.get('/getdata.php?date='+ encodeURIComponent(data), function(data) {
                $('#events').empty();
                $('#events').html(data).show();
                evt.preventDefault();

            });
        });

        function highlightDays(date) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
                if (dates[i].getTime() == date.getTime()) {
                    return [true, 'highlight'];
                }
            }
            return [true, ''];

        }  

    });
</script>

<style>
#highlight, .highlight {
background-color: #000000;
}
</style>  



<div id="datepicker" style="float:left;margin: 0 10px 0 0;font-size: 72.5%;"></div>

<div id="events" style="float:left;font-size: 10pt;height: 300px;">
<p>Select a date on the calendar to see events.</p>
</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Here it is with no php, just the HTML output

```
<link type="text/css" href="/css/calendar-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {


var dates = [new Date(2011, 11-1, 3),new Date(2011, 11-1, 11),new Date(2011, 11-1, 19),new Date(2011, 11-1, 26),new Date(2011, 12-1, 11),new Date(2012, 6-1, 16),new Date(2012, 7-1, 1),new Date(2012, 9-1, 20),new Date(2012, 10-1, 25)];


$('#datepicker').datepicker({
numberOfMonths: [1,1],
beforeShowDay: highlightDays
});


$('#datepicker').click(function(evt){
// put your selected date into the data object
var data = $('#datepicker').val();


$.get('/getdata.php?date='+ encodeURIComponent(data), function(data) {
$('#theevents').empty();
$('#theevents').html(data).show();
evt.preventDefault();

});
});

function highlightDays(date) {
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
if (dates[i].getTime() == date.getTime()) {
return [true, 'highlight'];
}
}
return [true, ''];

}  

});
</script>

<style>
#highlight, .highlight {
background-color: #000000;
}
</style>  



<div id="datepicker" style="float:left;margin: 0 10px 0 0;font-size: 72.5%;"></div>

<div id="theevents" style="float:left;font-size: 10pt;height: 300px;">
<p>Select a date on the calendar to see theevents.</p>

</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any script errors?

Comment: which particular version of IE?

Comment: no script errors and im in IE 8 but i dont think it works in 7 or 9 either, works in firefox, chrome, and safari

Comment: @user520300 Why do you have a nested document ready function? `$(document).ready(function() {...` is long hand for `$(function(){...`

Comment: I removed the one $function(){... still no go

Comment: Interesting new development, if i click the date which should return results from getdata.php nothing happens, if i click the date and then click somewhere above the numerical dates on the datepicker it does load the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `dates` array in JavaScript will have a stray trailing comma and that is probably making IE append a stray `null` to your array:

```
$dates .= "new Date(".$record[year].", ".$record[mon]."-1, ".$record[day]."),";
                                              # ----------------------------^
```

So your JavaScript looks like this:

```
var dates = [ new Date(...), new Date(...), ..., ];
```

and IE thinks that you mean this:

```
var dates = [ new Date(...), new Date(...), ..., null ];
```

And then, in your `for` loop inside `highlightDays`, you'll try to call `getTime()` on `null`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    if (dates[i].getTime() == date.getTime()) { // <---------- Right here
        return [true, 'highlight'];
    }
}
```

That will give you a run-time error in your JavaScript and then all your JavaScript stops working.

Fix your `var dates` to not include the trailing comma.

---

Once that's out of the way, it looks like you have a stacking problem with IE. The individual cells within the calendar will look something like this:

```
<td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery_1323234722897.datepicker._selectDay('#datepicker',11,2011, this);return false;">
    <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">1</a>
</td>
```

The `return false` in the `onclick` attribute is your problem. If you clear those attributes after binding the datepicker:

```
$('#datepicker td').attr('onclick', '');
```

then `#datepicker` should respond to your click. You'll probably want to move your `evt.preventDefault();` from the `$.get` callback up to the `click` handler as well.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/XanvW/4/

---

And if you want your click handler to be called after the date is chosen (rather than "instead of selecting the date" as I thought), then you want the [`onSelect` callback](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect):

> Allows you to define your own event when the datepicker is selected.

Comment: its not the trailing comma, or at least not in that section. notice i i rtrim the last comma out with php.  I added the HTML output so you can see with no php

Comment: @user520300: Does this fiddle work or does it show the same problem? http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/XanvW/

Comment: the fiddle highlighted the calendar just fine but there is no actions in this fiddle so clicking the highlighted date doesnt do anything.  It must have something to do with the $.get cause its not getting anyting or updating the events div

Comment: @user520300: And this one? I'm just adding things piece by piece. http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/XanvW/1/ BTW, having `evt.preventDefault();` inside the `$.get` callback is a bit odd and probably doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: no BUT yes with an interesting twist, if i click a date the alert doesnt work in IE, however if i click the date and then click somewhere not in the numerical area like the white space to the left of 1 for example it will alert the last numerical date i clicked.

Comment: Okay, so if you click on one of the numbers in the calendar, nothing happens but if you click in the empty areas of `#datepicker` (such as right under the day abbreviations) then you'll get an alert, right?

Comment: even if i click the day abbreviations it will alert just not if i click an actual date.

Comment: @user520300: Please have a look at my update, I think I've figure out what's going on and I have a possible kludge around it.

Comment: I clicked your demo and when i click on a date an alert is fired however its only alerting the current date ex 12/07/2011 its not alerting the value of the date i clicked

Comment: Then why aren't you using the `onSelect` callback? Look at the bottom of the "events" tab: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: @user520300: Well I'm the one that has been running around in circles trying to figure out how to do the wrong thing so don't feel too bad. Anyway, I added `onSelect` to my answer in case you want something to accept.